# How to alter databases tables at run time using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, openjpa

I am creating CRUD application for customer . and he asked me to allow him to create new Fields in a form (database columns) without restarting the application server. which JPA implementation should I use (hibernate , eclipselink ,openjpa)
to accomplish this task and how it will be done?

Comment: That's really not something you want to do.

Comment: JPA is for persistence, and one-off generation of schema to match that persistence, not for frigging about with schema.

Comment: eclipselink (AFAIAK hibernate too) have concept of 'dynamic column', IMHO hard to use in your context without customer and architect decision. It is not easy thema

Answer (score 2):

Please don't change the database schema at runtime.

Assuming, you would add a column to a table. Then you have to add a field in your entity class, too. And the mapping. So you not only have to change a Java class at runtime, at next application start, you must add this field again. No JPA implementation can do that.

Of course, you can use plain JDBC. And instead of entity classes with concrete fields you can use something like a map for your dynamic fields. But you should adapt all your SQL queries according to the presence of dynamic fields. So you need a way to store the information, which dynamic fields are already created. You can do this with another table or use the table meta information. Additionally you have to manage user defined field names. E.g you should avoid SQL keywords, there is a maximum field name length, etc.

Or you can step back and rethink your approach. You have a requirement: Static given fields in a form and the possibility to create dynamic fields.

Why not adapt your data model to that requirement? A data model which is able to handle dynamic form fields. Such flexible datamodel wouldn't need dynamic SQL table field creation. (And JPA can handle that, too.)

The simplest example would be a table with two columns. One for the field name and one for the value (as string). Maybe a third one to identify the type.

Another alternative would be to use a NoSQL database system like a key value store or a document oriented database.